# sort bar chart by sum of values in ggplot

Tags: r

example data:

```
player <- c("a", "b", "a", "b", "c", 
            "a", "a", "b", "c", "b", 
            "c", "a", "c", "c", "a")
is.winner <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
               FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
               TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)

df <- data.frame(player, is.winner)
```

my first graph looks something like this

[image]

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=player, y=as.numeric(is.winner))) +
  geom_bar(stat="summary", fun.y=sum) + 
  coord_flip()
```

What I would like to do is sort the df$player axis by the sum of "TRUE" values, so that it looks something like this:

[image]

I realize I could use something like this:

```
df$player <- factor(df$player, levels=c("b", "a", "c"))
```

But the actual data has far more 'player names'. In addition I would like to something similar with win percentages, etc. So automatic sorting would be great. Example of win percentage below

[image]

```
df$is.winner <- factor(df$is.winner, levels=c("TRUE", "FALSE"))
df$player <- factor(df$player, levels=c("c", "b", "a"))

library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=player)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=is.winner),position='fill')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2") +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `reorder` which is a function that reorders a factor's levels according to some predicate.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(player, is.winner, function(x){ sum(x) }), 
                    y=as.numeric(is.winner))) +
geom_bar(stat="summary", fun.y=sum) +
coord_flip()
```

[image]

`reorder(x, X, FUN)` takes

- `x`, the factor to reorder.
- `X` a vector of the same length as `x`. This vector will be split into subsets for each level and passed to the function `FUN`.
- `FUN` the function to apply to each level's subset. This function should take a vector and return a scalar that will be used to order the factor levels.

In your last example you need to convert the vector to boolean again to be able to sum it up:

```
df$is.winner <- factor(df$is.winner, levels=c("TRUE", "FALSE"))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(player, df$is.winner=="TRUE", sum), fill=is.winner)) +
  geom_bar(position='fill') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2") +
  xlab("player") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. Had seen reorder in a few searches but it never it the mark until now.

Comment: I've got a bit of a problem with the reorder statement above: `x=reorder(player, df$is.winner=="TRUE", sum` as the total count of wins does not necessarily mean the larger win percentage. Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: yeah, change `sum` to `mean`